# systemd amule-web not starts while the computer boots

Tags: boot, systemd

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I have setted up an amule-daemon and amule-web services that work.

here is my `/etc/systemd/system/amuled.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Amule daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "sudo -u myuser /usr/bin/amuled"
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "sudo -u myuser /usr/bin/amulecmd -c shutdown"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and my `/etc/systemd/system/amule-web.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Amule Web
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "sudo -u myuser /usr/bin/amuleweb"
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "sudo -u myuser /usr/bin/amulecmd -c shutdown"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I restart the computer and run `systemctl list-units --all | grep amule` I get this

```
amule-daemon.service  loaded    active   exited    LSB: Daemonized version of aMule.
amuled.service        loaded    active   running   Amule daemon
amuleweb.service      loaded    inactive dead      Amule Web
```

I don't understand why amuleweb.service is not starting on boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can clean up your `systemd` unit files by using the `User=` directive:

```
User=myuser
ExecStart=/usr/bin/amuled
ExecStop=/usr/bin/amulecmd -c shutdown
```

This is preferred over using `sudo`.

Second, you should become familiar with the basics of `systemd` status and logging commands. Check the `status` of your commands, which includes the last few logs as well as the full logs.

```
 systemctl status amuled.service
 systemctl status amuleweb.service
 journalctl -u amuled
 journalctl -u amuleweb
```

Third, `/var/systemd` is not a standard place to put your custom systemd unit files on Ubuntu. They should go in `/etc/systemd/system`

Finally, you should review the documentation for [`Type=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) and see if you need to set it to non-default value for the service you are trying to manage.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I made a mistake when I had written the question, the directory was `/etc/systemd/system`. I added the user and changed the commands. Finally my mistake was in my amuleweb.service I should have put `After=network.target amule-daemon.service amuled.service`